# In Opencart 2.0 OCMod, modified file is not used for view

Tags: php, opencart, vqmod, opencart2.x

I've deployed a sample Opencart2.0 under a subdirectory in my godaddy domain. I've created a OCMod xml file `remove_unused_desc_from_category.ocmod.xml` which removes a line from `<sub_dir>/catalog/view/theme/default/template/product/category.tpl`

I've installed this using Extension Installer and refreshed the cache. Then checked the new file `<sub_dir>/system/modification/catalog/view/theme/default/template/product/category.tpl` which had the change.

But it is still not affecting the UI. I'm still a learner of opencart and OCMod. Kindly help.

Comment: Don't use OCMod, use vqmod instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have asked the same question in [Opencart github repo here](https://github.com/opencart/opencart/issues/2215), and found the solution.

> If you installed opencart with an autoinstaller it migth have added DIR_CATALOG to your root config.php, you must edit it and remove it, it should not be there.And move its value directly to DIR_APPLICATION. - [florinsith](https://github.com/florinsith)

Code:

```
//define('DIR_CATALOG', '/home/<user_dir>/public_html/<sub_dir>/catalog/');
//define('DIR_APPLICATION', DIR_CATALOG);
define('DIR_APPLICATION', '/home/<user_dir>/public_html/<sub_dir>/catalog/');
```

Comment: You saved the day